# Restore RAID 5 HP P410

Tags: raid, hp-smart-array, data-recovery

I have:

- P410 + 512MB Battery Backup
- 4x4TB in RAID 5

I changed the PSU today and after starting OS (Windows 2008 R2) the array is gone.

ACU sees 2 HDD as unassigned and original RAID 5 as 2 OK and 2 HDD missing.

How can I restore the original array without losing data?

Comment: If the data is of any value, talk to either HP Support or contact a local data recovery company. Of course there are things you can **try**, but the results would be unknown and so would be at considerable risk.

Comment: WHY would you use RAID 5 with 4TB disks - nobody uses R5 any more, it's not the '90's - you're literally asking for data corruption.

Comment: ok what RAID you will recommended i have now 2x 12TB RAID 5 (4x4TB)

Comment: I need maximum space and fast read (write is not important because isn't often)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your first step is to recover the data. Recovery software can help here. Scan the drives with ReclaiMe it should find the RAID config parameters. R-Studio and UFSexplorer are also popular for RAID recovery.

Comment: R-Studio recognize my raid and I backup 90% of all data ( 10% is probably something what i deleted before raid was lost )